# In-house framework use SPM with precompiled *.xcframework cause ERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle... contains disallowed nested bundles

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm experience and Swift Package Manager (SPM) issue with precompiled binary `*.xc-framework`.

Here is the project's structure (run with `Xcode 12.5`):

[image]

Everything work fine, until I archive the project and send it to Appstore. I got this error:

```
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Application.app/Frameworks/Custom.framework' contains disallowed nested bundles.
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Application.app/Frameworks/Custom.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
```

When I look into the exported `*.ipa`, I see the `Custom.framework` contains `SVProgressHud.framework`, which it should be in Application level.

[image]

If I add the `SVProgressHUD.xcframework` directly, the exported *.ipa is in correct structure and the errors disappears.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to configure SPM to avoid this particular issue.
There are many libraries distributed this way ([Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk), [WebRTC](https://github.com/alexpiezo/WebRTC), [ArcGIS](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-toolkit-ios) ...), although I haven't seen any post related.

Any advice you could give would be much appreciated.

p/s: Here is the full source code for reference: https://github.com/nahung89/SPM-Test-Distribution